# Azure function timer trigger is running mysteriously

Tags: azure, timer, azure-functions

I've got one Azure function with a timer trigger for 01:00.
The function is V1 and I use c#-script for it. The function is doing an post request du another API.

Actually the function and the timer trigger works but sometimes I see that the function is triggered two times.

[image]

So as you can see the timer triggers my function every day on 01:00 but on the 4th of July it triggers the function also on 01:59. At this time everybody sleeps so I can exclude that the function was triggered manually at the portal or something else.

Where can I also check why the function has been triggerd?
In the eventlog I only found this a few seconds before the second rund:

```
<Data>
Recycling application MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MY-TIMER-TRIGGER [TID 22456][PID 27328]
</Data>
```

**UPDATE #1**
Here is the function.json of the function, if it is necessary

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 0 1 * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "outTable",
      "tableName": "myTableStorage",
      "connection": "myTableStorage_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: Are you doing deployments or anything similar at this time?

Comment: No, no deployment to the function or something else.

Comment: you sure you didnt manually trigger it?

Comment: Yes. No one was working at this time.

Comment: I'd expect this behavior if your function.json had `runOnStartup = true`, but that doesn't look to be the case here. Would you mind posting this as an issue on our [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host) so we can track it, and share your app's name (you can do so [privately](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately))?

Comment: Ok done: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4593